# Ubuntu Mate: Change font color of Desktop Icon

Tags: mate, gtk3, ubuntu-mate

How does one change the font color of Desktops Icon using Ubuntu 16.04 Mate and the gtk-theme Radiant-MATE from white to black?

I add at the ende of /usr/share/themes/Radiant-MATE/gtk-3.0/gtk.css these lines:

```
.nautilus-desktop.nautlius-canvas-item {
   color: #000000;
 }
```

I also tested

```
.caja-desktop.caja-canvas-item {
   color: #000000;
 }
```

None worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes must be made in

```
/usr/share/themes/Radiant-MATE/gtk-2.0/apps/caja.rc
```

Add somewhere

```
style "desktop-icon-black" {
    CajaIconContainer::normal_alpha = 0
    text[NORMAL] = "#000000"
    CajaIconContainer::frame_text = 1
}

widget_class "*DesktopIcon*" style "desktop-icon-black"
```

to get black colored font without shadows on Desktop.